# Have an error with cors, if my cors is enable?

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, express

I want to do a request get or post to my firebase backend api

this is my request

```
const verify = async (address) => {
  const params = { address }
  const { data } = await client.get('test', { params })
}
```

and my backend i am using cors

```
const app = require('express')()
const cors = require('cors')

const options = {
  origin: true,
  methods: 'GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS,HEAD,PATCH',
  preflightContinue: false,
  optionsSuccessStatus: 204,
}

app.use(cors(options))

app.get('/test', (req, res) => {
  console.log('console.log', req.body)
  res.status(200).send('hello world!')
})

module.exports = {
  Module: () => app,
}
```

I don't know what happened, but I am getting an error in cors:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://...functions.net/test?address=AABB' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you need to insert the URL, on which your Vue App is running into `options.origin`

Or does `options.origin: true` set headers to '"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": *'?

EDIT: First, you need `req.query.address` in order to access the address query param, that you sent from Vue.

EDIT: Without setting your `options` to `cors()` I get the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` Response Header from Express. Might not want to do this in production, but set origin to some URL that use the API.

```js
const app = require('express')()
 const cors = require('cors')

app.use(cors())

app.get('/test', (req, res) => {
  console.log('console.log', req.query.address)
  res.status(200).send(`The address is ${req.query.address || "not existing"}`)
})


app.listen(3000, () => console.log("Express running..."))
```

[image]

Comment: should i put http://localhost:8080 in origin? like this: var corsOptions = { origin: http://localhost:8080. ???

Comment: i tried with that does not worked

Comment: Well, you can try with "http://localhost:8080" - Why are you using the Firebase Client to communicate with your Express backend API? From Vue you could use `const response = await fetch("http://localhost:80/test")`

Comment: .listen() just is for my local right? or i need to change for production?

Comment: .listen() starts the express API. So, you likely need to tweak the host and port in production, but still need .listen() when running on a VM/server in production

Answer (score 1):

I use this. Find this solution on Stackoverflow :

```js
//#region CORS - Area...
var whitelist = [
  "http://127.0.0.1:3000",
  "https://127.0.0.1:3000",
  "https://localhost:3000",
  "http://localhost:3000",
];
var corsOptions = {
  origin: function (origin, callback) {
    if (whitelist.indexOf(origin) !== -1 || !origin) {
      callback(null, true);
    } else {
      console.log("Blocked-Origin:", origin);
      callback(new Error("Not in CORS-Origin-List"));
    }
  },

  methods: ["POST, DELETE, GET"],
  optionsSuccessStatus: 200,
};
app.use(cors(corsOptions));
//#endregion CORS - Area...
```

And this solution is not recommended, but for Test ok...

```js
app.use(
cors({
optionsSuccessStatus: 200,
credentials: true,
origin: "*",
 methods: ["GET", "POST", "DELETE"],
})
);
```

Note: `origin: "*",` not `true`

Comment: can i use origin:'*'?

Comment: Yes... but it's not recommended in production!